# Plotting multiple Y values per X Value to represent sample distribution with dots joined by lines

Tags: python, plot

I have a distribution of Y sample values for each X value. This is an example: [image: Example Plot]

How do I plot it with dots, with the lines joining the dots in Python, to show distribution of these Y values, similar to the example in the picture?

What type of plot is this?